# Why can't jump?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem that I can't jump but when i deleted the code :

```
rb.velocity = Vector2.right * vel;
```

it worked, so why can't i use them in the same time and how do I fix it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float vel = 7.5f;
    public float jump_vel = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            rb.velocity += Vector2.up * jump_vel;
        }
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * vel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because you override `rb.velocity` computed in the `if` statement by the second assignment of `rb.velocity`; (`rb.velocity = Vector2.right * vel;`).

(Edit)
To fix that, just use:

```
        Vector3 jumpVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            jumpVelocity = Vector2.up * jump_vel;
        }
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * vel + jumpVelocity;
```

Comment: then increase jump_vel